# Kernelized linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm

In kernelized linear regression, we find out that our weight vector $w$:

$$ w = \phi^{T}\alpha = \phi^{T}(K+ \lambda I)^{-1})y $$

Here, $K$ is the kernel matrix and $y$ label of the training instances and $\phi$ is the input feature mapped into a higher dimension.
In prediction we use:
$$H(x) = w^{T}\phi(x) = y(K+ \lambda I)^{-1})\phi^{T}\phi_{*}$$

Here, $\phi_{*}$ is the test point.

My question is if:
$$ w = \phi^{T}(K+ \lambda I)^{-1}y $$
Then how come:
$$ w^{T} = y(K+ \lambda I)^{-1}\phi^{T} $$
Should not it be:
$$ w^{T} = y^{T}(K+ \lambda I)^{-1}\phi $$

Refrence:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBVSbVktLIY at 4.45 and 6.37 minute

Comment: Do you have any reference to add?

Comment: Yes, I added the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the slides. It should be
$$H(x)=y^T(K+\lambda I)^{-1}\Phi\phi_*$$

I capitalised the transformed feature matrix of dimension $n\times p$, where $n$ is number of training data samples and $p$ is the new dimension. The test point, $\phi_*$ is of dimension $p\times 1$, so that the multiplication $\Phi\phi_*$ makes sense in linear algebra.

Also, note that in kernelized regression,
$$\Phi\phi_*=\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1^T\\ \phi_2^T\\\vdots\\\phi_n^T\end{bmatrix}\phi_*=\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1^T\phi_*\\ \phi_2^T\phi_*\\\vdots\\\phi_n^T\phi_*\end{bmatrix}$$

whose entries can be calculated from the Kernel function without the high dimensional mapping.